# HTML child items appearing larger than parent HTML element

Tags: css, html

I am creating a angular 2 recipe app. I have a problem with a html element though. The un-ordered list list items (containing check boxes) element is larger than the parent UL element. See screen shot.

[image]

Also, see my HTML:-

```
<tr>
  <td>
      Ingredients
  </td>
  <td>
    <ul formControlName="ingredient_id" name="ingredient_id" class="form-control checkbox-grid" required>
      <li *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients" value="{{ingredient.ingredient_id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ingredient.ingredient_id}}" name="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}" />
        <label for="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}">{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

See my .css:-

```
.checkbox-grid li { display: block; float: left; width: 25%;}
.checkbox-grid {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question and provide a working example as either a snippet/fiddle

Answer (score 0):

1) did you try giving width to parent ul ?
2) your li have float property so you have to use clear both at the end

Answer (score 0):

See css and *replace* your code :--

```
.checkbox-grid { 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px -10px;
  clear: both 
}
.checkbox-grid:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: table 
}
.checkbox-grid:after {
  clear: both
}
.checkbox-grid li {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 25%; 
   padding:0px 10px
}
.checkbox-grid li:nth-child(5n){
  clear: left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out. Looks like Bootstrap css was overwriting the height of the form-control class element. Bootstrap css was:-

```
.form-control {
    height: 34px;
}
```

I just changed my style.css to over write:-

```
.form-control.checkbox-grid {
    overflow:hidden ;
    height: auto;
}
```